# Docker run throwing servlet expections

Tags: docker

I have started the WebSphere Application Server(WAS) on docker, which is running fine.

When the java application is deployed and started on it, it throws the below error:

```
    [6/7/23 6:00:55:394 UTC] 00000012 FileRepositor A   ADMR0009I: Document cells/DefaultCell01/cus/claims-admin-ear/cver/BASE/controlOpDefs.xml is created.
[6/7/23 6:00:55:395 UTC] 00000012 FileRepositor A   ADMR0009I: Document cells/DefaultCell01/applications/claims-admin-ear.ear/deployments/claims-admin-ear/claims-services-web.war/WEB-INF/web.xml is created.
[6/7/23 6:00:55:395 UTC] 00000012 FileRepositor A   ADMR0009I: Document cells/DefaultCell01/applications/claims-admin-ear.ear/deployments/claims-admin-ear/claims-services-web.war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF is created.
[6/7/23 6:00:55:396 UTC] 00000012 FileRepositor A   ADMR0009I: Document cells/DefaultCell01/applications/claims-admin-ear.ear/deployments/claims-admin-ear/claims-services-web.war/WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xml is created.
[6/7/23 6:00:55:396 UTC] 00000012 FileRepositor A   ADMR0010I: Document cells/DefaultCell01/nodes/DefaultNode01/serverindex.xml is modified.
[6/7/23 6:01:01:216 UTC] 00000013 AdminHelper   A   ADMN1009I: An attempt is made to start the claims-admin-ear application.
[6/7/23 6:01:01:231 UTC] 00000013 CompositionUn A   WSVR0190I: Starting composition unit WebSphere:cuname=claims-admin-ear in BLA WebSphere:blaname=claims-admin-ear.
[6/7/23 6:01:02:367 UTC] 00000013 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I: Starting application: claims-admin-ear
[6/7/23 6:01:02:368 UTC] 00000013 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0203I: Application: claims-admin-ear  Application build level: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[6/7/23 6:01:04:864 UTC] 00000013 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: XXXClaimsAdminWeb.
[6/7/23 6:01:05:538 UTC] 00000013 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Failed to load listener: au.com.aiaa.claims.web.StartupSystemCheckListener]: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        **The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved
        The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved
        The import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils cannot be resolved
        The import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory cannot be resolved
        The import org.springframework.context cannot be resolved
        The import org.springframework.jndi cannot be resolved
        The import com.ibm cannot be resolved
        The import com.ibm cannot be resolved
        The import com.ibm cannot be resolved**
        ServletContextListener cannot be resolved to a type
        ServletContextEvent cannot be resolved to a type
        ServletContextEvent cannot be resolved to a type
        BeanFactory cannot be resolved to a type
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type
```

The application is deployed and started as below, the above shown errors are logged in the docker WAS console. I am also unable to access the URL : http://localhost:9080/ClaimsAdminWeb/app

```
C:\claims>docker exec -it claims-ws /work/deploy-claims-app.sh claims-admin
  ###################################################
  # XXX Webshpere Docker Image (CLAIMS)             #
  ###################################################

  Deploying app [/claims-admin/claims-admin-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear]...

Attemping to uninstall app...
   Nothing to do!
... completed!

Installing application...
Application claims-admin successfully installed!

Starting application...
Application claims-admin successfully started!
```

Any idea, what I need to check?.

Thanks

Comment: Please include a[mcve] containing the Dockerfile, your build configuration (pom.xml/build.gradle) and the code of `au.com.aiaa.claims.web.StartupSystemCheckListener`.